# What does "to throw down" with somebody mean?

Tags: meaning, phrases, idioms

I can't find the following phrase in an dictionary: "to throw down" [with somebody]. What does it mean?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

"[To throw down](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=throw%20down)" means to fight someone (usually physical).  It's a colloquial expression.

Interestingly, one entry on Urban Dictionary attributes its origin to "throwing down the gauntlet" an old tradition of throwing down ones gloves to challenge someone. The person challenging the other would throw down his glove or gauntlet, and the person accepting the challenge 'would take it up'.

You also see it used in popular culture like the TV show *[Throwdown with Bobby Flay](http://www.foodnetwork.com/throwdown-with-bobby-flay/index.html)*, which is a show where Bobby Flay challenges people to cooking competitions.

Comment: Not to be confused with "to throw down cash" which usually means "to contribute to".

Comment: Or throw up with Sb. Vomiting is a symptom of Antimony poisoning

Comment: Yes, but throwing up *with somebody* is probably food poisoning.  Or an eating disorder.

Comment: Note this example from the early 1900s: "when he threw down on me I put up my hands and he shot me": http://goo.gl/znPhU